# Solve Lognormal equation for mu and sigma given fixed y and x in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

I have the equation of the lognormal:

> y = 1/(3.14*x*sig)*exp(-(log(x)-mu)^2/(2*sig^2))

and for fixed

> y = a
>
> x = b

I need to find the values of mu and sig. I can set mu in Matlab like:

> mu = [0 1 1.1 1.2...]

and find all the values corresponding sig values, but I can't make it with solve or subs. Any ideas please???

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is your input and what do you want to compute? Parameters of the underlying normal to/from the parameters of the lognormal?

Comment: The inputs are y=constant, x=constant, and a vector that represents several values of sigma. I want to know the value of mu given x, y, and the values of sigma...Thanks!

Comment: Are you **not allowed** to use `solve`/`subs` or you simply don't know how to use it in this context?

Comment: I don't know how to use them in this context... I assume that those would be the right commands. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to get the multitude of possible lognormals, the probability density of which lies on a specific given point?

Comment: yes, the mus and sigmas for x=const and y=cont

Comment: I think there can be in general two `mu`s for every `sigma`: one with a peak before `x` and one after it. Have you thought about this? Does this make sense? Anyway, if you look for `sigma(mu)` then this should not be a problem.

Comment: So, I would do this using `fzero`: solving the function `y-f(x,mu,sig)` for 0, for each given `mu`. This will give you a `sig` for each `mu`, if you're lucky. The function is a bit ugly, so I don't know how easy it will be for it to find the zero (but if there is indeed a unique zero, then it should be easy).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please indicate how to write that in fzero?

Comment: I added an answer, but didn't check if it actually worked. Let me know how it turned out, and if you have any questions.

Comment: Note that I added some generalizations and fixed some typos in the code, so if you got errors then retry with the current version. If you get `NaN`s, that's another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept to use `fzero` to numerically search for a `sigma(x,y,mu)` function.

Assuming you have `x,y` fixed, you can set

```
mu = 1; %or whatever
myfun = @(sig) y-1./(3.14*x*sig).*exp(-(log(x)-mu)^2./(2*sig.^2)); %x,y,mu from workspace

sigma = fzero(myfun,1);
```

This will solve the equation

```
y-1/(3.14*x*sig)*exp(-(log(x)-mu)^2/(2*sig^2))==0
```

for `sig` starting from `sig==1` and return it into `sigma`.

You can generalize it to get a function of `mu`:

```
myfun2 = @(mu,sig) y-1./(3.14*x*sig).*exp(-(log(x)-mu).^2./(2*sig.^2));
sigmafun=@(mu) fzero(@(sig)myfun2(mu,sig),1);
```

then `sigmafun` will give you a `sigma` for each value of `mu` you put into it. The parameters `x` and `y` are assumed to be set before the first anonymous function declaration.

Or you could get **reaaally** general, and define

```
myfun3 = @(x,y,mu,sig) y-1./(3.14*x*sig).*exp(-(log(x)-mu).^2./(2*sig.^2));
sigmafun2 = @(x,y,mu) fzero(@(sig)myfun3(x,y,mu,sig),1);
```

The main difference here is that `x` and `y` are fed into the function of `sigmafun2` each time, so they can change. In the earlier cases the values of `x` and `y` were *fixed in the anonymous functions at the time of their definition*, i.e. when we issued `myfun = @(sig)...`. Depending on your needs you can find out what you want to use.

As a proof of concept, I didn't check how well it behaved for the actual problem. You should definitely have an initial idea of what kind of parameters you expect, since there will be many cases where there's no solution, and `fzero` will return a `NaN`.

---

**Update by Oliver Amundsen:** the resulting `sig(mu)` function with `x=100, y=0.001` looks like this:

[image: figure]

Comment: I did x = 100; y = .001; Mu = linspace(2,7); for i = 1 : 100; xx(i) = sigmafun(Mu(i)); end. And seems that's only defined from mu=2 to 7.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen as I discreetly hid in my answer, you have to *first* define `x` and `y`, *then* define the function, if it uses workspace variables as parameters. So before your `for` and after your `x=...; y=...` stuff, issue the `myfun2=@(mu,sig) ...; sigmafun=@(mu)...` stuff

Comment: Yeah pretty much the same thing with this message: Function may not have a root.
Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
    because no sign change is detected during search. and got many NaNs

Comment: @OliverAmundsen Those messages are due to the two bands of NaN's. If you do it right, you'll see a bunch of valid solutions between a bunch of `NaN`s in `xx`. Issuing `Mu(find(~isnan(xx),1,'first'))` and `Mu(find(~isnan(xx),1,'last'))` will tell you the extremal values of `Mu` for which there's a solution: `2.7071` and `6.4949`.

Comment: Right, so it seems that this is the answer.

Comment: @OliverAmundsen for this pair of `(x,y)`, yes, it would seem. You can try playing around with the starting point of `fzero`, but it's probably right. You can plot some of the resulting probability densities, and see for yourself if there could be further solutions which we missed (I'm guessing the graphs of these densities will be very talkative).